# Batch programming - some questions

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem with understanding a batch file that is a part of a task (sort of hackme).
I find it hard to find informations about it in google, i dont know, i feel like there isnt any good batch language documentation or soemthing other that is solid.

my first question, what it does?  It is possible to *dont* satisfy the condition ?

```
if not "!"=="" (
echo Authorization failed!
pause>nul
exit
)
```

Secound question, what this kind of IF's does ?:

```
set %1.pass=%2
if "!%1.pass:~5,1!"=="" (
```

.....

```
if not "!%1.pass:~6,1!"=="" (
```

Thank you,

@EDIT

technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340(v=ws.10).aspx

i have read it, it doesnt answer my questions

Comment: The official reference of the batch language is at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: i have read it before i posted and it doesnt answer my questions, its really poor reference.

Comment: Re your first question: Is the code the real source code, or is it what is echoed during execution? The latter would have variables replaced. If you e. g. would have a variable %ABC% that is not set, then `if not "!"=="%ABC%" (` would be echoed like the first line of your code during execution.

Comment: It is a real code. Its a batch script that takes one argument
<x.bat> passsword

Maybe it is a part of a task to delete this if (he is on the start of a file), just dont know if it have any sense.

Comment: See http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php for some string manipulation examples in batch scripts. This explains the ~n,m syntax for substrings.

Comment: This question doesn't belong on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might check it out by yourself:

```
@echo off &SETLOCAL
if not "!"=="" (ECHO NOT equal) ELSE ECHO equal
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if not "!"=="" (ECHO NOT equal) ELSE ECHO equal

SET "property.pass=ABCDE"
ECHO %property.pass:~0,1% %property.pass:~1,1% %property.pass:~2,1% %property.pass:~3,1%
```

Output is:

```
NOT equal
equal
A B C D
```